# Using vertical UIScrollView with horizontal paging

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

So, what I need: 3 pages (with swipe support): two of them just fit the screen, third one must have vertical scrolling.

1) Can you provide what bunch of controls I need to use: ScrollView with vertical scrolling inside parent `ScrollView` with paging enabled? Or `ScrollView` with `PageControl`?

2) How to adjust vertical `ScrollView`. I've read bunch of question here, and tried to do that by myself.
I tried to add 4 constraints for `ScrollView` (pin it to parent edges), then I add child `UIView`, also pin it to Scroll edges. Then I add some rectangles to child view, and using different settings I got: just horizontal view, horizontal+vertical scroll, only vertical scroll but with top space from `UINavigationBar` and with clipped some height from child rectangles (I can't scroll to them).

Can someone provide some example of how to do that? I prefer IB for constraints, but if it's necessary to calculate some math in code - it's ok.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When paging between view's like that, I would suggest using a UIPageController (You can easily get a sample application by creating a new project and selecting "Page Based Application"). Change the transition style from Page Curl to Scrolling and there is the functionality you need for paging between view controllers. Now you just can place a scroll view in your third view controller and make sure the attributes are as follows. `DirectionLockEnabled` is the key to what you are trying to do, as it determines if scrolling is disabled in a particular direction (this case horizontal scrolling). Using this type of solution, it is then really easy to set constraints because you're setting constraints for 3 separate view controllers rather than 3 views within a scroll view

edit: disable "Shows Horizontal Indicator" Checkbox also

[image: scroll view]